# Need to Disable the setOnClickListener while the ImageView is loading in background

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am loading `ImageView` using the below code from URL

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", this.getPackageName()); 
chat_home.setImageResource(resID);
```

while I refresh the page, `ImageView` (i.e `chat_home`) is disappear for several second during that time I have to discard the `chat_home.setOnClickListener`. Once the `ImageView` is displayed in the screen, then I want to enable the `chat_home.setOnClickListener`.

```
chat_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(checkInternetConnection())
                {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                //intent.putExtra(MainActivity.check, result);
                    startActivity(intent);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    // my toast                             
             }
            });
```

So my question is how to check whether the imageview is filled or empty in the screen.

Comment: chat_home.setOnClickListener(null);

Comment: make chat_home.setEnable(false) and chat_home.setClickable(false)

Comment: How do I check the condition whether the Imageview is loaded or not, then only I can set chat_home.setOnClickListener(null); depending upon the condition.

Comment: Are you refreshing page using refresh button?

Comment: yes, I place my refresh button in header, i.e in action bar.

Comment: Why don't you load the image in background task. You can use async task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the "loading" part is when you're calling

`chat_home.setImageResource(resID);`

Just create a flag that is false until this method executes (so set it to true immediately after this statement).

Then, in your onClickListener,

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(flag) { 
              // execute code
            } else {
              // do nothing
            }
        }
```

Comment: if I set flag, it is always true in both the case

Comment: I want to catch the time different when the image is loaded after the refresh is completed.

Comment: "create a flag that is false until this method executes" how can it be true in both case?

Comment: will edit my answer as well for clarity. you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use Universal image loader. in that there is several methods are as under.

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and display Bitmap in ImageView (or any other view 
//  which implements ImageAware interface)
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView, displayOptions, new ImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        ...
//here you can set 
view.setEnable(false)
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        //here you can set 
view.setEnable(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
        ...
    }
}, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current, int total) {
        ...
    }
});
```

For loading image you need use one of the method.
    String imageUri = "assets://image.png"; // from assets
    String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image; // from drawables (only images, non-9patch)

**Note:**
 To use universal image loader library you have to configure first.for that all instruction given in below link.

[Universal-image-loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)